# Unlimited loop while using win32com in Python

Tags: python

I faced unlimited loop while running win32com.
The code is as the following, there's no error or msgs, any help is appreciated in this regard. Thank you in advanced!

```
    data : [{'filename':'example1.docx'},{'name':'John'},{'filename':'example2.docx'},{'name':'Jan'}]

    for i in data:
        name1 = i["[filename]"]
        name2 = now.strftime("%d%m%Y") + '__' + i["[filename]"]
        word = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
        word.Documents.Open(os.path.abspath(name1))
        word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(os.path.abspath(name2))
        word.ActiveDocument.Close(False)
        word.Quit()
```

Comment: try to create the word instance & quit it _outside_ the loop. It's not useful and wasteful to open/close word for each document. Try that and report back

Comment: What makes you think it keeps running? Also, `name1 = i["[filename]"]` is a KeyError.

Comment: by the way: what are you trying to achieve? copying a document? you could just use a file copy without using word.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre So...basically, I have an excel file and the text of each row will be replaced to words of matching docx file. Now only the first row can work.

Comment: @roganjosh I think it keeps running coz only the first docx file be changed and saved, also i can't give any command to terminal. I have to  close it forced and re-open it.